# Conflict resolution with breeze

Tags: javascript, concurrency, breeze, optimistic-concurrency

How can conflict resolution be achieved in breeze.sharp or breeze.js and how does it compare to the newly released Azure "AsyncTable" conflict handling?

The scenario is this: An entity (e.g. Person) is saved in the breeze cache from a previous fetch from the server (the reason for saving the data in the cache is to make it possible for the user to work on the app while the mobile device is disconnected from the internet). While the mobile device is offline the user edits some details on the Person (e.g. edits the surname). Meanwhile someone else edits the same Person's surname and that is successfully saved back to the Azure (or central MS SQL) database. Then the mobile device comes online again and sends its update (which has been stored in the local cache until now) to the server.

My question is, how can/should it be done with breeze to open up the possibility to pick the "winner" between these two conflicting updates? The mechanism for deciding the winner is not the issue here. I'd just like to know how best to get the opportunity to make that decision - and then how to let the winner's version of the surname be persisted on the loser's side (i.e. the mobile device or the server DB).

The closest I managed to get to an answer for this is in the breeze documentation on the "Saving changes" page where it says "This page is not ready for publication. It will cover: ... Concurrency and the DataProperty.concurrencyMode".

I am not sure whether this requirement can be properly implemented through optimistic concurrency or whether something more akin to the Azure way of approaching this (Version fields on the entities and other unbeknownst-to-me magical conflict resolution and sync logic) would be required to make this work on breeze?

Comment: `DataProperty.concurrencyMode` is just Breeze's way of identifying a property used for optimistic concurrency; typically a `rowversion` property.  Breeze will automatically increment such properties when an entity is updated.

Comment: Are you looking for automated conflict resolution (the app or server picks the winner), or manual resolution (the user is presented with the choice)?

Comment: Hi Steve, I realise now that concurrency only has to do with same-second type scenarios, whereas conflict resolution is about a longer timeframe (e.g. when a field is updated while the device is offline it might be hours or days before the device comes online again, so concurrency features will do me no good). There will be custom logic to decide which should be the winner and that could go on the client or server. No UI interaction is required. Would it be an option to override the SaveChanges method on the server-side maybe?It would be nice if there were a tried and tested way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd just like to know how best to get the opportunity to make that decision - and then how to let the winner's version of the surname be persisted on the loser's side (i.e. the mobile device or the server DB).

I'm using breeze with an Entity Framework / MS SQL backend.  Here's how I'm identifying concurrency exceptions on the client:

```
export function isConcurrencyException(reason: any): boolean {
  return reason.message && /Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows/.test(reason.message);
}

entityManager.saveChanges()
  .fail(reason => {
    if (isConcurrencyException(reason)) {
      // ... concurrency exception handling logic ...
    }
    // detect other failure reasons (connection issue, server-side validation error, etc)
  });
```

In terms of what to do after you've identified a concurrency exception, that's tough, every app is different.  There's a several scenarios to consider, ranging from non-conflicting property edits, conflicting property edits as well as situations where another user deleted an entity you're trying to save.  Breeze's [MergeStrategy](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MergeStrategy.html) will likely come into play in your solution.